# Unpredicted tensor shape after dynamical slicing

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am relatively new to TF and am wondering how to get tensor slice dynamically,  from a unknown shape of tensor?

I want to get the weights from the last layer (`output_layer`) and do softmax and then only look at those indices on the 2-nd dimensions (from the `out_reshape`). The numpy-type of striding didnt work, so I am using `tf.gather` instead (after changing the axis so that the desired axis is on the first axis).

And this works:

```
out_reshape  = tf.gather(out_reshape, [1,2,3,4])
```

This outputs a tensor with [4, 3, ?] (as we expected). But I want to change the indices based on the data fed to `T` (instead of `[1,2,3,4]` as shown above).
this gives an unpredicted result (as shown in the code below):

```
out_reshape  = tf.gather(out_reshape, T)
```

and

```
out_reshape.shape
```

this gives `TensorShape(None))`, but **I was expecting to get [?, 3, ?], where the first value is the same length as `T`** (the data fed into the `T` is an 1-d ndarray, such as `[100, 200, 300, 400]`). 
What is going on here? Why its output shape collapses to None?

The entire code is something like this:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
tf.reset_default_graph()

with graph.as_default():

    y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape =(31, 3, None), name = 'Y_observed') # (samples x) ind x seqlen 
    T=tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape =(None), name = "T_observed")
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (None, None, 4)  , name = 'X_observed')

    model = Conv1D(filters = 16, 
                   kernel_size = filter_width, 
                   padding = "same", 
                   activation='relu')(x)    
    model = Conv1D(filters = 16, 
                   kernel_size = filter_width, 
                   padding = "same", 
                   activation='relu')(model)
    model = Conv1D(filters = n_output_channels, 
                   kernel_size = 1, 
                   padding = "same", 
                   activation='relu')(model) 

    model_output = tf.identity(model, name='last_layer')
    output_layer = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('last_layer:0')

    out = output_layer[:, 512:, :]     
    out_norm = tf.nn.softmax( out, axis=1 )

    out_reshape = tf.transpose(out_norm, (1, 2, 0))   # this gives a [?,3,?] tensor
    out_reshape  = tf.gather(out_reshape, T)   # --> Problematic part !  
    ...
    updates = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize....
    ...
```